# Pentaho BI Server won't run on my 32bit Windows 7 computer

Tags: windows, installation, pentaho

My 32bit Windows 7 server is running `Pentaho bi server ce 7.0`.

Everything seemed to install fine, but I'm having trouble getting the server to run.

**Attempt 1**

Everything seems OK after running `start-pentaho.bat` and accessing `localhost:8080`, however accessing `localhost:8080\Pentaho\login` returns an error.

**Attempt 2**

I am unable to access the site after running `start-pentaho.bat` and accessing `localhost:8080`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Which Java version is the BI process running in?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the BI Server is only supported on 64-bits OSes all the way back to version 5.1. The documentation for 4.4 is already gone from the Pentaho support site.

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0D0/160/000